# Reading Data and Returning Outputs in Mathematica Modules

Tags: module, wolfram-mathematica

I am new to Mathematica and want to ask perhaps a very simple question :-).

I need to read data from an input file and then process it. Due to its repeated use in my code, I make a module. An Example is given below.

```
MySubr[b_, e_, d_] := Module[{a, c},      
f = OpenRead["Input File.dat"];
A = Read[f, Number]; 
T = Read[f, Number]; 
WL = Read[f, Number];
RO = Read[f, Number];
a = b*RO;
c = d*A+e*T-WL;
Return[{a, c}];
]
```

When I call this module;

```
{a,c}=MySubr[2,3,4]
```

I get the following error;
    Set::shape: Lists {a,c} and MySubr[{2,3,4}] are not the same shape.

I am not sure what the error is and how can I solve this problem. All of you are requested to suggest something useful and simple.

Thanks

Comment: the error indicates you have called `MySubr[{2,3,4}]` not `MuSubr[2,3,4]`.  Important difference...

Answer (score 0):

It will help you debug your code if you run this and see where it breaks :-

```
{b, e, d} = {2, 3, 4};
f = OpenRead["Input File.dat"];
A = Read[f, Number];
T = Read[f, Number];
WL = Read[f, Number];
RO = Read[f, Number];
a = b*RO
c = d*A + e*T - WL
```

Comment: Thank you Chris! I have attempted that and it is running fine unless I add Module definition into it. The form which you show is absolutely running fine. If you could comment on addition of module, that will be of great help. Thanks again

Comment: @user3367664 - george's comment seems to be correct.